# Ruby on Rails 3: How can I sort ActiveRecords by an attribute of another table?

Tags: activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to query a database table and get the rows ordered by a count of an association. Is there a Rails (like Active Record Query) way to do this?

My models and their associations are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :business
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :postulations
end

class Postulation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :business
end
```

I need to get a number of Users ordered by the amount of Postulations that their Business has. Is there a clean way to do this or do I just have to query with find_by_sql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.includes(:business => :postulations).group("users.id").order("count(postulations.id) desc").limit(20)
```

This will probably work

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know. I didn't know about the includes function.

Comment: Yep, worked! Thanks! I ended up needing something a bit different (had to add another restriction), but I managed to do it with your help. The includes function is very useful!